# missionaries and cannibals heuristic

Tags: greedy

I want to implement missionaries and cannibals with python with different search algorithms. One of the algorithms is `Greedy` or `A*` that needs a heuristic function to work.

I cant think of any correct heuristic to work. Can you suggest a heuristic ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @c-otto I want a heuristic function to work.

Comment: please make sure to at least try and provide your ideas on how you approached the problem.
also, these kind of question might be more relevant at https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct heuristic function for missionaries and cannibals problem, we assume that in the first place, there are 3 missionaries and 3 cannibals on the left side, so :

```
h(x) = (cannibalsLeft + missionariesLeft) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
heuristic = (no. of missionaries at right side + no. of cannibals at right side) – 1
```

The minus 1 (– 1) in the above expression is important to keep the heuristic function admissible